# jquery not showing live data unless refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to count the amount of dropdowns that have a specific item selected in them. I have my code below, but it works like this:

select options in the drop downs, press refresh page, selected items in drop down remain there, and the script reads the amount of times each were selected.

The dropdown boxes are listed on the page with questions. there are about 100 dropdowns. every drop down has the same options.

this is a repeating code that lists all the drop down selections on the right side of the page, and shows the number of how many times each was used next to it. it works, just not dynamically. I want it to work instantly when an item is selected, without having to make selections and then refresh.

```
<%
 mySQL="SELECT * FROM admins WHERE area="&parea&" AND type>2"
 call getFromDatabase(mySQL, rstemp4, "addscheduleform5.asp") 

do while Not rstemp4.EOF 

pempidw=rstemp4("idadmin")
pempname1=rstemp4("firstname")

%>

 <%=pempname%>=

<script type="text/javascript">


var scheduled = $("select").filter(function() {
return $(this).val() == "<%=pempidw%>";
});
document.write(scheduled.length);



   </script>  


<%rstemp4.movenext
  loop%>
```

EXAMPLE:

For example, if you have 5 dropdowns. so if you select

> X, A, B, X, A

in the drop downs, the code reads

> X=2 A=2 B=1

Now it works, if you make your dropdown selections, and refresh the page, the drop down selections remain the same, and the code reads the amount of times each were selected.

Now if you change your first option from

> X to A,

then the code still reads:

> X=2 A=2 B=1

unless you refresh the page, then you see:

> X=1 A=3 B=1.

For those that don't know asp, this javascript function has nothing to do with my site being asp. the `"<%=pempidw%>"` simply displays a number on the loaded page, referencing the select value.

see below what the loaded script would appear as.for reference on what `"<%=pempidw%>"` means only

```
<option value="2">2</option>

<script type="text/javascript">
var scheduled = $("select").filter(function() {
return $(this).val() == "2";
 });
 document.write(scheduled.length);
</script>
```

Comment: You would need to bind to the `change` event of the drop-downs if you want "live" data. Currently it only executes at initial visit to the page.

Comment: @BradChristie ok great. how would i implement the "change" event into this?

Answer (score 0):

Given `document.write` really isn't a good way of doing this, I'm going to (for the sake of the example) place a `<span id="result"></span>` on thepage we can [re]reference with the output.

Having said that, the test code should be wrapped in a function so we can re-use it. Currently it's only executing on the initial visit to the page. To correct that, we're also going to execute our new function on a change to any of the dropdowns.

```
function getSelectedValues(){
  var matches = $('select').filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() == '<%=pempidw%>';
  }).length;
  // here's where we just update that new <span>
  $('span#result').text(matches);
}

// call it on initial page visit
getSelectedValues();

// and here we bind to the change event for the selects
// and re-call our above function.
$('select').on('change', getSelectedValues);
```

Comment: The only problem i have found was that the data was remaining the same for all parts of the repeating code, and not individually, so i had to add  $('span#result<%=pempidw%>').text(matches);  and <span id="result<%=pempidw%>"></span>  to make each unique

Comment: So each select was being tabulated? It was hard to tell without seeing any real `<Select>` elements. But glad it worked for you. ;-)

Comment: yes- i rendered the code to make 1000 drop downs appear and tested every few to see and it worked beautifully. thanks so much

Comment: how would i be able to get this to work on only a specific div? "var matches = $('.group1 select')"

Comment: if `<div class="group1">`, then you have it.